# SQL Delete all rows in a table based on another table and another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

table1:

```
|   ID        |  POST STATUS   |
|   12807     |  wc-refunded   | 
|   13075     |  wc-refunded   |
```

table2:

```
|   ORDER ID  |  -------   |
|   12807     |  -------   | 
|   13075     |  -------   |
```

Let me explain better, i want to delete all ORDER ID  in table 2, based on all ID of table 1 if post_status = wc-refunded

MYSQL VERSION: 5.7

**EDIT**: fixed with first solution from the @Tim Biegeleisen (***THANKS!***)

```
    DELETE
FROM wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_posts
              WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions.order_id AND wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-refunded');
```

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: @nbk mysql 5.7..

Comment: Tim Bigelson answer are ok, please show  a dbfiddle where you can reproduce your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exists logic:

```
DELETE
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
              WHERE t1.ID = t2.ORDERID AND t1.poststatus = 'wc-refunded');
```

We can also try using delete join logic:

```
DELETE t2
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.ID = t2.ORDERID
WHERE t1.poststatus = 'wc-refunded';
```

Comment: i am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: I have given multiple valid answers to your question.

Comment: @swish. . . If this answer helps you, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
DELETE FROM table2 
WHERE OrderID IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT ID 
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE PostStatus = 'wc-refunded'
                 )
```

It is a bit resource intensive, but should work...

Comment: thanks for you answer, already fixed with another code, dont tried with your code, but i think this is will work too